# How to have a proper alphabetic pager with number support?

Tags: views, 6, paging

I'm trying to achieve an alphabetic pager with grouping of special characters + numbers.

All pagers available do 0|1|8|9|A|B|C, while I want 0-9|A|B|C or #|A|B|C, # being for special characters and numbers.

To illustrate it better, here is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Alphabetic Pager goal]

I'm using Drupal 6 and views 6.x-2.12.

I already searched a lot for this, and also tried asking here at http://drupal.org/node/908716, but I did not have success.

I don't mind solving this with "hackish" methods, but I'm not being able to come up with one of those.

Thank you, in advance.

Comment: I recently started putting together a blog post showing how I did exactly this a few months ago using a custom module to create a new filter handler for views. I finished it up and posted here: http://garandwebtech.com/blog/2011/creating-alphabetical-filter-numeric-category-drupal-views-using-custom-filter-handler Once you set up the new filter you just need to link # to pass the right parameter.

Comment: Holy mother! I did not expect that someone would have a solution for this so quickly and elegantly. Impressive, might I say.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20121026103756/http://garandwebtech.com/blog/2011/creating-alphabetical-filter-numeric-category-drupal-views-using-custom-filter-handler